# how to decide the reshuffle frequency？

Tags: sharding

Currently, Ethereum adopts reshuffle to prevent collusion between validators, and similar designs are also used in other sharding schemes. For example, reassembling shards or replacing nodes in shards.
The effectiveness of this approach is obvious, but there is no explanation on how often a reshuffle is needed. In my opinion, the frequency of reshuffles is related to the capabilities of adaptive adversaries. If the adversaries corrupts other nodes with strong capabilities, more frequent reshuffles are required. But the capabilities of adversaries are not clearly defined and don't know how to quantify them? Does anyone know on what basis Ethereum has determined the current reshuffle frequency? Is there any relevant research or paper